# RadTimePicker display time from a Store Procedure value VB:net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, telerik

On a VB.net website i  run a SP that returns a datetime value and i need to pass this value in to a RadTimePicker for display, the format that i get back id the next:

'#5/1/2014 7:05:00 AM.# {Date}

i use the Tostring method and than substring to get only the time

```
lector("BBIT_01ManEntra").ToString.Substring(10, 12)
```

that returns the value like this

"7:05:00 a.m."

All of this need to append on the click o a button

```
Private Sub rbCargar_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbCargar.Click
    lector = objBd.BitacoraGuardada()
    While lector.Read
        If Not lector("BBIT_01ManEntra") Is DBNull.Value Then rtpEmañana1.SelectedTime = TimeSpan.Parse(lector("BBIT_01ManEntra").ToString.Substring(10, 12))
    End While
End Sub
```

but whe it runs i get this error:

FormatException was unhandled by user code

For this to work i need the time in a 24 hr format not 12 hr
can any one help me to make this work or showme a dierent wasy to fet to diapaly the time on the control please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40(v=vs.110).aspx) to parse the time substring, and [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) to get a 24-hour value:

```
Dim time = DateTime.Parse("7:05:00 AM")
Dim time24 = time.ToString("HH:mm")
```

Comment: Thanks man i just made some changes to make it work with i already had. i pend a lot of time trying everything and nothing work. :D your the man. my code looks like this now:

If Not lector("BBIT_01ManEntra") Is DBNull.Value Then rtpEmañana1.SelectedTime = TimeSpan.Parse(DateTime.Parse(lector("BBIT_01ManEntra").ToString.Substring(10, 12)).ToString("HH:mm"))

Answer (score 0):

Is `lector("BBIT_01ManEntra")` typed as DateTime?  If so, we may be able to shorten it and give you a compatible time format with this rtp control you mentioned.

```
If Not lector("BBIT_01ManEntra") Is DBNull.Value Then rtpEmañana1.SelectedTime = TimeSpan.Parse(lector("BBIT_01ManEntra").ToString("HH:mm"))
```

Comment: I @JimmySmith thanks for the replay and yes lector("BBIT_01ManEntra") is datetime. i already try what you suggested but still get the error message: InvalidCastExeption, Conversion from string "HH: mm" to type 'Integer' is not valid. im usin Visual Studio 2010 Framework 4.0

Comment: I've never used the TimeSpan structure to do this, what happens when you try, `DateTime.Parse(lector("BBIT_01ManEntra").ToString("HH:mm"))`

Comment: Disregard, I see that must've been the case